# How should I setup a GWT project to be deployed in WebSphere?

Tags: java, gwt, websphere

I'm new to IBM Rational Application Developer. I'm running RAD 7.5.5 and want to use GWT as the front end for an application I'm writing. What I'm asking is basically if someone has had experience with this, and if so, explain in a few simple steps how it's done or maybe refer me to an example somewhere online where this is explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploying to WebSphere is no different then deploying to any other Application Server, or even a servlet container. You just need to compile your GWT app and package it in a WAR/EAR file. You deploy the application and have whatever HTML file you want the GWT app to appear in, include the nocache.js.

If you generate your app either using the command line script, through Eclipse, or with Maven, this HTML file will be generated for you. GWT is server agnostic, unless you want to use GWT-RPC, in which case you need a Java backend. You could run GWT on a plain Apache server if you wanted.